# Should I be using type assertion when creating an array of <type> | undefined objects?

Tags: typescript

What's the best route to take when trying to do the following in Typescript:

I have an object which looks like the following:

```
export interface TestConfig {
    configSql: MsSqlDatabaseConfig | undefined;
    userSql: MsSqlDatabaseConfig | undefined;
}
```

I later want to create an array out of the two configs in the object, like this

```
let dbConfigs: MsSqlDatabaseConfig[] = [config.configSql, config.userSql];
```

However Typescript reports that `MsSqlDatabaseConfig | undefined is not assignable to type MsSqlDatabaseConfig`, which makes sense.

But if I have guaranteed earlier in my code that these values aren't undefined, what's the best way to allow the compiler to use these values in my array? I need the `| undefined` as I have async calls which retrieve the data, and I can't use async methods in my class constructor so the values have to start out as undefined.

Casting the types of the two values seems like I'm shoehorning the types into the array.

```
let dbConfigs: MsSqlDatabaseConfig[] = [<MsSqlDatabaseConfig> config.configSql, <MsSqlDatabaseConfig> config.userSql];
```

Is there a better way?

Edit

The method resetDatabaseToKnownState() is called first before anything else which extracts some values from my env file and parses them into a valid object. The configSql and userSql values are then present from this point onwards.

```
public async resetDatabaseToKnownState(): Promise<void> {
        // Setup
        this.testConfig = await this.getSetupConfig();
    }

    private async getSetupConfig(){
        let configSql: MsSqlDatabaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.configDatabaseInfo!);
        let userSql: MsSqlDatabaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.userDatabaseInfo!);

        return {
            configSql: configSql,
            userSql: userSql
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"But if I have guaranteed earlier in my code that these values aren't undefined..."* In the normal case, TypeScript can see that you've done that, narrow the type for you, and not  raise the error. Can you show us how you've done that? We may be able to help you see why TypeScript isn't able to see it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have updated the OP. I know about the `!` operator, however I'm trying to avoid my code being littered with them. However it seems I can't have it both ways

Comment: Fixing what you've described sounds like it would require larger changes than we can suggest here (e.g., finding a way not to have the same object both A) possibly have undefined values and B) definitely not have undefined values). Perhaps rather than having a side effect, `resetDatabaseToKnownState` could return the known-not-to-be-`undefined` version of the object? That sort of thing. It may not be possible, and if possible it may be a bigger change than you can make right now, but that's the sort of thing. :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> But if I have guaranteed earlier in my code that these values aren't undefined...

In the normal case, TypeScript can see that you've done that, narrow the type for you, and not raise the error. For example:

```typescript
function example(x: {value: string | undefined}) {
    if (x.value) {
        console.log(x.value.toLocaleLowerCase()); // No error
    }
}
```

So you may be able to adjust your code to ensure that TypeScript can see you've narrowed the type.

In the rare situation you **have** to do an assertion, the simpler way is to use the `!` postfix "not null or undefined" TypeScript operator:

```typescript
let dbConfigs: MsSqlDatabaseConfig[] = [config.configSql!, config.userSql!];
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

`!` is a type assertion, so like all type assertions it's best to avoid where possible. Sometimes doing that requires larger structural changes than the simple example shown above.